# Paramatise query without using ExecuteCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Given the query:

```
db.ExecuteCommand(
    "UPDATE ForumUserStats SET Posts += {0} WHERE UserID = {1} AND ForumID = {2}",
     -1, post.AuthorID, post.Forum.ID
);
```

There are various points in the code where it would be better to save the queries into a `StringBuilder` and then execute them in one `ExecuteCommand` statement.

How can I add a query like above into a string ready to execute at a later date without having a `DataContext` available?

Please note, `string.format` does not properly paramatise the properties for SQL (eg with `DateTime` and `strings`).

Comment: By using `ExecuteCommand` directly, It looks like you are already moving away the conventions enforced from EF / Linq2Sql ORMs anyway. One of the more performant ways to do high frequency insert / upserts is to return to basic `ADO.Net`, establish a long lived Command (which in turn will use the established Connection Pool), and then you can [reuse the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376455/314291) and then just rebind the values on each transaction.

Comment: Save both query and parameters?

Comment: You should look into [how does sqlparameter prevent sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)